# Windows 10 Upgrade Dual Monitors Broken

Tags: windows, windows-10

I updated from **Windows 8.1** to **Windows 10**, and when I did so, I am no longer able to run dual monitors.

I am on a **Toshiba Satellite S855-S5378** and I have tried <kbd>Windows + P</kbd> and the menu that pops up says:

> Your PC can't project to another screen. Try reinstalling the driver or using a different video card.

What is caused this to stop working upon upgrading?

I got my windows 10 download from [this download link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

Driver:

```
Microsoft Basic Display Adapter: 
    Version: 10.0.10586.0
```

CPU-Z Info:

```
Graphic APIs
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

API             Intel I/O

Display Adapters
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Display adapter 0   
    Display name        \\.\DISPLAY3
    Name            Microsoft Basic Display Adapter
    Board Manufacturer  Toshiba
    Memory size     0 MB
    PCI device      bus 0 (0x0), device 2 (0x2), function 0 (0x0)
    Vendor ID       0x8086 (0x1179)
    Model ID        0x0166 (0xFB20)
    Performance Level   0
        Core clock  342.8 MHz

Win32_VideoController       AdapterRAM = 0x0 (0)
Win32_VideoController       DriverVersion = 10.0.10586.0
Win32_VideoController       DriverDate = 06/21/2006
```

Comment: Did you "*Try reinstalling the driver or using a different video card*"?

Comment: @Ramhound I tried, but it says that the ones I have are newer than the one I was trying to install.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I uninstalled the one that I had an windows just reinstalled it.

Comment: @Ramhound I was quoting the error to make a point.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Add that to the question then, or it looks like you're asking what to do when the error tells you.

Comment: I have added more information, I hope it is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I see it looks like you need the most recent Intel video driver. The one you have installed is a generic video driver that may or may not have all the functionality and is only there to allow you to see basic video.

You can do that by find what you need by using their auto detect feature here--> http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect

Or you can check Toshiba's website for their video card and search the model for Intel on their main search section for drivers here--> https://downloadcenter.intel.com/

Once that is done make sure in your Personalization settings you set the monitor to EXTENDED and not duplicate. Also make sure it is not setting the resolution to something to high the monitor can't handle.

Comment: Downloading the **Intel® Driver Update Utility** Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a AMD Radeon R7 and after trying everything, including changing registry files, I managed to sort it in BIOS. Option for dual monitors had been disabled in the upgrade